# How many times will the show function execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed that it will print many times when I scroll once.Does it mean that the show function excute as many times as printing?

```
 $(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 1000) {
            $(".goTop").show();  
            console.log("hello");
        } 
    });
```

});

Comment: yes, it does run show every time

Comment: Whenever you scroll, the scroll events emits. That's why the function gets called multiple times.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem.  Pretty sure you already know that all the code is being run (why wouldn't it?).  What are you really asking?  What's the issue of it "executing" .show()?   Looks like you're asking how to `debounce` the scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes show will be called as many times as console.log is done. Inside if you can have one more condition where you can check `$(".goTop")` is shown(disply property should not be none) or not.

Answer (score -1):

I think whenever the scroll is more than 1000 and user starts to scroll this function happens so you have to check that if scrollTop is more than 1000 and goTop element is hidden then it happens once

Comment: Scroll event is fired by the browser *as* the user scrolls, not when they start to scroll.

Comment: so when user scrolls this event is fired that's what i said

Comment: As my *emphasis* shows - you stated *"user **starts** to scroll this function happens"* - that indicates that it only fires **once** - when the user **starts** to scroll.  It continues to fire while the user is scrolling, not just once at the start.  Maybe you "meant" that, but that's not what you said.